# Google Drive is not even installed on the iPhone but it consumes a lot of time

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-apps, screen-time

My girlfriend has an iPhone 13 and she doesn't even have Google Drive on her phone, but according to the screen time we've noticed that Google Drive consumed 15h 32m today. And looking at the App Store, it is shown like it has been installed before and uninstalled. She has an iPad Pro 4th Gen that has Google Drive on it though. We are worried if we are hacked or something. Is it a common thing or are we in trouble? Any kind of help is appreciated.[image]

[image]

Comment: Does she have any other Google owned apps like YouTube or apps that require Google Drive?

Comment: She has YouTube, Gmail and YouTube Music on her phone

Comment: We've seen a device called "iPhone 14.5" in the list of signed in devices. We've changed the passwords and logged out on every device. I hope this was nothing but a bug or something.

Comment: Google Apps are the most notorious for sending data back to Google servers.  This includes app storage and tracking info I would try DeGoogling your life. Start with a clean slate and don’t install any Google apps.  If you use gmail, use a client like Mail or Outlook.

Comment: It has been installed on the device at some point, otherwise it wouldn't have the cloud icon.